# Suppose that the random variable X has PDF...

Tags: probability

I've tried to do this question but I'm not sure if I'm correct or not. I also have no idea how to do (c) [not even sure what shortcut he's talking about bit I can ask a classmate]

Here is my file with the question and my attempt at (b) : [image: work]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do b), first calculating the cdf $F_Y(y)$ of $Y$. Note that $F_Y(y)=0$ if $y\le 0$, and $F_Y(y)=1$ if $y\ge 1$.

Now we calculate the cdf for $0\lt y\lt 1$. We have
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(X^2\le y)=\Pr(-\sqrt{y}\le X\le\sqrt{y}).$$
So
$$F_Y(y)=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{x+1}{2}\,dx.$$
Integrate. Conveniently, the $\frac{x}{2}$ part integrates to $0$, and we get $F_Y(y)=\sqrt{y}$ for $0\lt y\lt 1$.

For the density function, differentiate $F_Y(y)$.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your help. So for differentiating, am I also differentiating with x? or y? Like would my answer be 1/(2(sqr(y))

Comment: @NookLines: You are welcome.  Yes,  $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$ for $y\in(0,1)$ and $0$ elsewhere.